# Remover Elementos Repetidos de uma Lista[0] a parti do indice da Lista[1]

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tenho uma estrutura de lista dentro de lista (lista=[[ ],[ ]]). Exemplo:

```
lista = [['pedro', 'marcos', 'mario', 'pedro', 'marcos', 'mario'],[5.2, 2.2, 6.1, 6.2, 1.1, 5.0]]
```

Estou tentando remover os elementos repetidos da primeira lista com base na segunda lista o de maior valor será atribuído para nova lista.
Exemplo de saída:

```
lista_saida = [['pedro', 'marcos', 'mario'],[6.2, 2.2, 6.1]]
```

Este é um rascunho que realizei sem sucesso:

```
lista = [['pedro', 'marcos', 'mario', 'pedro', 'marcos', 'mario'],[5.2, 2.2, 6.1, 6.2, 1.1, 5.0]]
lista_saida = [[],[]]
elemento = []
maior_indice = 0
for i in range(len(lista[0])):
    for j in range(len(lista_saida[0])):
        if lista[0][i] == lista_saida[0][j]:
            x = lista[1][i]
            y = lista_saida[1][j]
            if x >= y:
                maior_indice = lista[1][i]
                elemento = lista[0][i]
            else:
                maior_indice = lista_saida[1][j]
                elemento = lista_saida[0][j]
    else:
        maior_indice = lista[1][i]
        elemento = lista[0][i]
        
lista_saida[0].append(elemento)
lista_saida[1].append(maior_indice)
```

Saída de meu codigo:

```
[[[], 'marcos', 'mario', 'pedro', 'marcos', 'mario'],[0, 2.2, 6.1, 6.2, 1.1, 5.0]]
```

Qualquer ajuda com a lógica é bem vinda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lista = [['pedro', 'marcos', 'mario', 'pedro', 'marcos', 'mario'],[5.2, 2.2, 6.1, 6.2, 1.1, 5.0]]
```

```
nova_lista = [[],[]]

for l, j in zip(lista[0], lista[1]):
    
        if l not in nova_lista[0]: 
            nova_lista[0].append(l)
            nova_lista[1].append(j)
        if l in nova_lista[0] and nova_lista[1][nova_lista[0].index(l)] < j:
            nova_lista[1][nova_lista[0].index(l)] = j
```

Saída:

```
print(nova_lista)
[['pedro', 'marcos', 'mario'], [6.2, 2.2, 6.1]]
```

Existem várias possibilidades de resolver, essa é uma delas.

No primeiro if verificamos se os itens ainda não existem na nova lista, caso não exista adicionamos o item. No elif verificamos se o item já existe dentro da nova lista, caso exista, verificamos se o valor float é maior que o que já existia, caso positivo alteramos, caso negativo passamos para a próxima iteração.

Comment: Otima resposta, resolveu o problema proposto. Eu repliquei sua codificação e funcionou perfeitamente no exemplo apresentado, contudo quando eu inserir uma lista mais extensa com 5000 elementos o codigo dar um erro na linha do elif: **IndexError: list index out of range**, poderia me ajudar?

Comment: poderia me passar os dados de teste?

Comment: João, eu estava comparando `nova_lista[1][lista[0].index(l)]` o que levaria ao erro pois eu deveria comparar com `nova_lista[1][nova_lista[0].index(l)]`. Do jeito que estava eu não comparava os valores dentro do vetor correto. Acho que foi o sono kkkk. Atualizei o código. Abraço!

Comment: "serviu como um luva" a atualização do codigo. Obrigado por disponibilizar de seu tempo para me ajudar. Abraço!